# Recording video by the hour to file (avconv/ffmpeg)

Tags: bash, cron, avconv

I'm currently recording video from my IP camera to disk by making use of avconv (ffmpeg).

```
avconv -i rtsp://192.168.1.1/stream -c copy pool.mp4
```

However, I'm in need of following and have not been able to successfully get it running from a bash script or cron.

- Create a new file per hour and name it accordingly
- I have to support multiple cameras
- I need to limit to a weeks worth of recordings whereafter the oldest gets deleted.
- I want to manage this via a bash script and/or cron job as far as possible.

Thanks
John

Comment: Great. What have you done so far? Note we cannot do it for you, but help whenever you have a specific problem.

Comment: Command-line usage questions are off-topic here. Questions can be migrated to [su].

Comment: Not sure I agree w/ LordNeckbeard, besides the answer is mostly answered already in a SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567490/stop-avconv-bash-script-on-user-input-and-continue-loop